# Using Ajax to read a csv/text file

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv

I want to use ajax to read a text file and convert it into an array to fill in a select box. The problem is that I cannot figure out why the ajax code will not work. Every time I test out the code in Chrome, I get this error from jQuery:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/filepath.../AttributeCategories.txt. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Here's the HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "AttributeCategories.txt",
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    processData(data);
                }
            }); 
        });

        function processData(data){
            var attrcsv = data.split("\n"); //----------------------------------split the csv into rows
            var ctgyList = attrcsv[0].split(","); //----------------------------split the first row into categories

            for(var i = ctgyList.length + 1; i > 0; i--){//---------------------trim empty items off the array
                if(isNaN(ctgyList[i]) == true){ctgyList.splice(i,1);}
            }

            $('#sel')[0].options.length = 0;//----------------------------------clear select options
            for(var i = 0; i < ctgyList.length; i++){//-------------------------build select from the array
                $('#sel').append($('<option>',{value:i + 1,text:ctgyList[i]}));
            }
        }
    });
    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr><td><button id="btn">Click Me!</button></td></tr>
            <tr><td><select id="sel"></select></td></tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
```

All of the files (HTML and the text file) are in the same folder.
Any help or clarification would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: You can't read a local file.

Comment: You have to host your code on a (local) server.

Comment: If you want to read files, utilize the file reader API in HTML5 and you can do callbacks for asynchronous experience.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is explained in the error message. For security reasons, your browser does not allow you to request asynchronously an URL from a different domain than the page running ("cross-origin request"). For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy and https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.